# How can I get logged user ID in JHipster : Not the Username

Tags: java, spring, jhipster

```
public static String getCurrentUserId() {
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
    String login = null;
    if (authentication != null) {
        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails)
            login = ((UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        else if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof String)
            login = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
    }

    return login;
}
```

I used above way to get user name. But I want to get logged user ID. Can I get that from **SecurityUtils.java**.

Comment: Have you tried using `getUserWithAuthorities()` method from `UserService`? Please edit your question with more details like which authentication type you're using and which context you want to get this id.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it:

```
  String userLogin = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().orElseThrow(() -> new 
    AccountResourceException("Current user login not found"));
   
  Optional<User> user = userRepository.findOneByLogin(userLogin);
  user.get().getId() <--- this is the ID
```